# Understanding components nesting in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

learning VueJS and going through some of the tutorials online including the guide on vuejs.org and I'm having one hell of a time understanding how components can be nested and have them communicating through props.

Simple example seem to be ok but the following code (slightly tweaked but pretty much out of the VueJS guide) is giving me trouble.

I cannot seem to be able to have 'blog-item' nested within 'blog-items.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain the big picture of how components could be nested along with the use the v-for directive.

I have gone through many tutorials and everything seems to work one the component is nested inside the top-level 'app' component that's supplying the data but I cannot seem to be able to translate that into the scenario below.

As a newbie, I could be missing a key concept or totally off the rails understanding Vue :)

hope you can help.

thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Components Basics - from vuejs.org</title>
    <!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">

      <!-- This works. I get it. -->
      <div id="components-demo">
        <button-counter></button-counter>
        <button-counter></button-counter>
        <button-counter></button-counter>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <!-- This works too and I get it. -->
      <div id="blog-post-demo-simple">
        <blog-post-simple title="My journey with Vue"></blog-post-simple>
        <blog-post-simple title="Blogging with Vue"></blog-post-simple>
        <blog-post-simple title="Why Vue is so fun"></blog-post-simple>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <!-- This is where I'm totally confused -->
      <!-- How do I structure this to make sure blog-items is binding the 'post'  -->
      <!-- correctly? What is not clear to me is where the directives should be placed -->
      <!-- Vue keeps complainig with the following: -->
      <!-- Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render -->
      <blog-items>
        <blog-item
          v-for="post in posts"
          v-bind:key="post.id"
          v-bind:post="post">
        </blog-item>
      </blog-items>

      <hr>

    </div>

    <script>

      // Define a new component called button-counter. Cool. No problem here.
      Vue.component('button-counter', {
        data: function () {
          return {
            count: 0
          }
        },
        template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
      })

      // This is also clear.
      Vue.component('blog-post-simple', {
        template:
        '<h3>{{title}}</h3>',
        props: {
          title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          }
        }
      })

      Vue.component('blog-items', {
        data() { return {
            posts: [
              { id: 1, title: '1. My journey with Vue' },
              { id: 2, title: '2. Blogging with Vue' },
              { id: 3, title: '3. Why Vue is so fun' }
            ]
          }
        }
      })

      Vue.component('blog-item', {
        template:
        '<h2>{{post.title}}</h2>',
        props: ['post']
      })

      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app'
      })

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember when you access a property in a template you're fetching that property from the component that uses that template. In this case it's your root `#app` component. Since that component doesn't have a property or method with the name `posts` then Vue is going to complain. What you need to do is move that part within the `blog-items` component's template since that component is holding your posts.

So what you need to do is this ..

```
    <!-- This is where I'm totally confused -->
    <!-- How do I structure this to make sure blog-items is binding the 'post'  -->
    <!-- correctly? What is not clear to me is where the directives should be placed -->
    <!-- Vue keeps complainig with the following: -->
    <!-- Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render -->
    <blog-items></blog-items>
```

---

```
Vue.component('blog-items', {
    template: `
    <div>
        <blog-item v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id" v-bind:post="post" />
    </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [
            { id: 1, title: '1. My journey with Vue' },
            { id: 2, title: '2. Blogging with Vue' },
            { id: 3, title: '3. Why Vue is so fun' }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

Otherwise you'll have to resort to using [Scoped Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots), which allow you to expose properties/methods from the child component's scope to the parent ..

```
<blog-items>
    <template slot-scope="{ posts }">
        <blog-item v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id" v-bind:post="post">
        </blog-item>
    </template>
</blog-items>
```

---

```
Vue.component('blog-items', {
    template:`
    <div>
        <slot :posts="posts"></slot>
    </div>`,
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [
            { id: 1, title: '1. My journey with Vue' },
            { id: 2, title: '2. Blogging with Vue' },
            { id: 3, title: '3. Why Vue is so fun' }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

I found [this](https://adamwathan.me/the-trick-to-understanding-scoped-slots-in-vuejs/) especially helpful in understanding how scoped slots work.

Comment: 1st, thanks for the quick reply. I get what you are saying and my (i guess flawed) thinking was to do what you're suggesting by including the template in the html. By mimicking the `<div id="blog-post-demo-simple">` structure I had assumed I was doing just that. which now brings to the question of how to embed the component's template in the html rather than as a property of the component by nesting components using their names? thx.

Comment: @djeetee for that, you'll want slots ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: @djeetee In `<div id="blog-post-demo-simple">` you're just statically assigning a `title` attribute and not trying to access a property with `v-for` or `v-bind` like you do in the latter case. Since you're mounting your root component to the `#app` div it's  treating everything within that div as being the root component's template. Since the root component doesn't have the properties you're trying to access and they're only available in the child component's scope then you'll have to expose those properties to the parents using scoped slots. I've updated my answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: thank you @phil & @Husam. the above is still somehow hazy but it's slowly clicking into place :) one final question if I may... What is the difference between creating a component using `Vue.component('comp-name', {})` and binding one to a `div` using `new Vue({ el: 'comp-name'})` ? thanks.

Comment: Don't worry it'll click eventually :) Maybe @Phil can post an answer that helps explain this in a better way.

Comment: Regarding your last question. `Vue.component` is the way to [globally register a component]. When you register a component globally it becomes available everywhere. It can be used in the root component's template, in other components' templates, and it can even be used [recursively within its own template](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Recursive-Components). This is fine for demos and small apps, but is usually advised against in large apps.

Comment: This is because globally registered components are made available throughout your app, so if you use a bundler like webpack to bundle your app and get rid of unused code, all globally registered components will end up in your final bundle whether you end up using them or not. This becomes a problem if, for example, you create a component library to use in your projects and you register all of your components globally.

Comment: `new Vue` on the other hand [creates a new Vue instance](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Creating-a-Vue-Instance). If you provide an element through the `el` option or the `mount` method the instance gets mounted to that element and becomes it's root Vue instance.